# If $\left\Vert A\right\Vert \geq c$ then $\left|\lambda\right|>c$ for all eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $A\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}$ be an invertible matrix such that$\left\Vert A\right\Vert \geq c$
where $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert $ is the matrix norm . Is it true
that for every $\lambda$ eigenvalue of $A$ we have $\left|\lambda\right|\geq c$?

I know that $\left\Vert A\right\Vert \geq\left|\lambda\right|$ but
why would $\left|\lambda\right|\geq c$?

Also Im familiar with the norm inequality $\left|Ax\right|\leq\left\Vert A\right\Vert \left|x\right|$
but couldn't use it in favor. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is $\lVert A\rVert$? Is it $\lVert A\rVert=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert=1}\lVert Ax\rVert?$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider any diagonal matrix of the form $A = \begin{pmatrix} c & 0 \\ 0 & \varepsilon I_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}$ where $I_{n-1}$ is the $n-1 \times n-1$ identity. Then $||A|| = c$, so clearly $||A|| \geq c$, but all its other eigenvalues are $\varepsilon < c$.

Comment: Could nilpotent matrix be invertible?

Comment: Ah sorry, misread.  I didn't realize that the matrix needed to be invertible.

Comment: Also, to answer your question, no.  If a matrix has a zero eigenvalue then it is not invertible.

Comment: @Jon Indeed it couldn't, for otherwise $A^n = 0$ would imply $I = (A^{-1})^n A^n = 0$.

Comment: @Jon I edited above to answer your question.

Comment: If you add $\epsilon$ on the diagonal, it becomes invertible and constitutes a counter example for small enough $\epsilon $